# Android - Changing title of MX player

Tags: android, android-intent, rtmp

I have made an app which streams live RTMP videos using MX Player (other alternatives are welcomed).

But when I stream a video (by sending a link via intent), MX Player shows the title as the last word of the link. For example, if the link is

> rtmp:example/live

the title will be **live**. But I need to change it.

How can I? As a beginner any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When using an Intent to launch an application, you are effectively transferring control to another app (in this case MXPlayer).

You can't make changes to that app unless they somehow expose those options in their Intent structure.

Bottom line, unless the developers of MXPlayer make this possible, there is nothing you can do, since you are using an external player (which you can't control).

Comment: how can i play rtmp links in videoview?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you are using *MX Player* then use this. Code works for me:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.putExtra("title","(here put your name)");
```